# Validity of Salat in case of touching with a woman

Tags: salat

If we accidentally touch a mahram woman (Sister) during prayer, is our prayer invalidated? I was offering prayer and she accidentally touched with me.
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hanafis, merely touching a woman does not break wudu and hence it should also not invalidate salah. The evidence for this is the hadith:

> عن عائشة ـ رضى الله عنها ـ قالت كنت أمد رجلي في قبلة النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وهو يصلي، فإذا سجد غمزني فرفعتها، فإذا قام مددتها
>
> Narrated Aisha:
>
> I used to stretch my legs towards the Qibla of the Prophet (ﷺ) while he was praying; whenever he prostrated he touched me, and I would withdraw my legs, and whenever he stood up, I would restretch my legs.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1209)</sup>

Another relevant hadith is:

> خرج علينا النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وأمامة بنت أبي العاص على عاتقه، فصلى فإذا ركع وضعها، وإذا رفع رفعها‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) came out towards us, while carrying Umamah, the daughter of Abi Al-As (the maternal granddaughter of the Prophet ﷺ) over his shoulder. He prayed, and when he wanted to bow, he put her down, and when he stood up, he lifted her up.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:516)</sup>